# How do I show docker pulls as an image in my github readme file

Tags: docker, github, icons, badge, hub

How can I add my "docker pulls", "build status", ... as a nice image / icon / badge in my README.md file ?
I'm using github with an autobuild link to docker hub.

update: I found out about badges but could use some clarification.

- https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges \
- https://github.com/Naereen/badges/blob/master/README.md

Example:

```
![Trueosiris Rules](https://img.shields.io/badge/trueosiris-rules-f08060)
[![Docker Pulls](https://badgen.net/docker/pulls/trueosiris/godaddypy?icon=docker&label=pulls)](https://hub.docker.com/r/trueosiris/godaddypy/)
[![Docker Stars](https://badgen.net/docker/stars/trueosiris/godaddypy?icon=docker&label=stars)](https://hub.docker.com/r/trueosiris/godaddypy/)
[![Docker Image Size](https://badgen.net/docker/size/trueosiris/godaddypy?icon=docker&label=image%20size)](https://hub.docker.com/r/trueosiris/godaddypy/)
![Github stars](https://badgen.net/github/stars/trueosiris/docker-godaddypy?icon=github&label=stars)
![Github forks](https://badgen.net/github/forks/trueosiris/docker-godaddypy?icon=github&label=forks)
![Github issues](https://img.shields.io/github/issues/TrueOsiris/docker-godaddypy)
![Github last-commit](https://img.shields.io/github/last-commit/TrueOsiris/docker-godaddypy)
```

[image: Trueosiris Rules]
[image: Docker Pulls]
[image: Docker Stars]
[image: Docker Image Size]
[image: Github stars]
[image: Github forks]
[image: Github issues]
[image: Github last-commit]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Individual CI/CD providers often provide build status badges directly (e.g. [Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/) and [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/blog/status-badges/)).

There are also a number of sites which provide more general badges.  For example, you could take a look at [shields.io](https://shields.io), which can do lots of badge types, including Docker Hub pulls, and build status for lots of popular CI/CD providers.  For example:

`https://img.shields.io/docker/pulls/mashape/kong.svg`